# Calling a PostgreSQL function using Java takes an extremely long time to get the result

Tags: java, postgresql

everyone. I have a servlet which can be called up via a GET query. Within this method I make a database call to a PostgreSQL. However, I am only calling one function of PostgreSQL. This provides me with around 20 fields, which also contain JSONArray and images (byte). This call or the duration until the result comes takes about 30 seconds, if not sometimes longer. My Java code is as follows. Where could you change something so that the call goes much faster?

```
@GetMapping(value = "/Gesamtabfrage")
@CrossOrigin
public void f_pp_all_s(HttpServletResponse response,HttpServletRequest request) {
    
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

    
    String userEntschluesselt = entschluesselUserId(request);
    String aktuellerUser = request.getParameter("aktuellerUser");


    Connection con = DBVerbindung();
    CallableStatement properCase = null;
    PrintWriter out = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try {
        out = response.getWriter();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    
    JSONArray ArrayJS = new JSONArray();
    
    
    if (con != null) {

        try {

            con.setAutoCommit(false);
            properCase = con.prepareCall("SELECT * FROM ppm.f_pp_all_s(?)");
            
            
            if(aktuellerUser != null)
            {
                properCase.setString(1, aktuellerUser);
            }
            else
            {
                properCase.setString(1, userEntschluesselt);
            }
            
            
            rs = properCase.executeQuery();
            con.commit();

            ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();
            int intRS = meta.getColumnCount();
            
            

            while (rs.next()) {

                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

                for (int i = 1; i < intRS + 1; i++) {

                    String column_name = meta.getColumnName(i);

                    switch (meta.getColumnType(i)) {
                    
                    
                    
                    case 2003:
                        //System.out.println("2003 ColumnName:" +column_name + " = " +meta.getColumnType(i));
                        obj.put(column_name, rs.getArray(column_name));
                        break;
                    case -5:
                        //System.out.println("-5 ColumnName:" +column_name + " = " +meta.getColumnType(i));
                        obj.put(column_name,
                                rs.getLong(column_name) == 0 ? JSONObject.NULL : rs.getLong(column_name));
                        break;
                    case 16:
                        //System.out.println("16 ColumnName:" +column_name + " = " +meta.getColumnType(i));
                        obj.put(column_name, rs.getBoolean(column_name));
                        break;
                    case 2004:
                        //System.out.println("2004 ColumnName:" +column_name + " = " +meta.getColumnType(i));
                        obj.put(column_name,
                                rs.getBlob(column_name) == null ? JSONObject.NULL : rs.getBlob(column_name));
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        //System.out.println("8 ColumnName:" +column_name + " = " +meta.getColumnType(i));
                        obj.put(column_name,
                                rs.getDouble(column_name) == 0 ? JSONObject.NULL : rs.getDouble(column_name));
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        //System.out.println("6 ColumnName:" +column_name + " = " +meta.getColumnType(i));
                        obj.put(column_name,
                                rs.getFloat(column_name) == 0 ? JSONObject.NULL : rs.getFloat(column_name));
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        //System.out.println("4 ColumnName:" +column_name + " = " +meta.getColumnType(i));
                        obj.put(column_name,
                                rs.getInt(column_name) == 0 ? JSONObject.NULL : rs.getInt(column_name));
                        break;
                    case -9:
                        //System.out.println("-9 ColumnName:" +column_name + " = " +meta.getColumnType(i));
                        obj.put(column_name,
                                rs.getNString(column_name) == null ? JSONObject.NULL : rs.getNString(column_name));
                        break;
                    case 12:
                        //System.out.println("12 ColumnName:" +column_name + " = " +meta.getColumnType(i));
                        obj.put(column_name,
                                rs.getString(column_name) == null ? JSONObject.NULL : rs.getString(column_name));
                        break;
                    case -6:
                        //System.out.println("-6 ColumnName:" +column_name + " = " +meta.getColumnType(i));
                        obj.put(column_name,
                                rs.getInt(column_name) == 0 ? JSONObject.NULL : rs.getInt(column_name));
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        //System.out.println("5 ColumnName:" +column_name + " = " +meta.getColumnType(i));
                        obj.put(column_name,
                                rs.getInt(column_name) == 0 ? JSONObject.NULL : rs.getInt(column_name));
                        break;
                    case 91:
                        //System.out.println("91 ColumnName:" +column_name + " = " +meta.getColumnType(i));
                        obj.put(column_name,
                                rs.getDate(column_name) == null ? JSONObject.NULL : rs.getDate(column_name));
                        break;
                    case 93:
                        //System.out.println("93 ColumnName:" +column_name + " = " +meta.getColumnType(i));
                        obj.put(column_name, rs.getTimestamp(column_name) == null ? JSONObject.NULL
                                : rs.getTimestamp(column_name));
                        break;
                    default:
                        //System.out.println("DEFAULT: ColumnName:" +column_name + " = " +meta.getColumnType(i));
                        obj.put(column_name,
                                rs.getObject(column_name) == null ? JSONObject.NULL : rs.getObject(column_name));
                        break;
                    }

                }

                ArrayJS.put(obj);

            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {

            Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Logger.GLOBAL_LOGGER_NAME);
            logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
            logger.warning(e.getMessage());

        } finally {

            if (rs != null) {
                try {
                    rs.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if (con != null) {
                try {
                    con.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (properCase != null) {
                try {
                    properCase.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    out.print(ArrayJS);
    out.flush();

}
```

Comment: You should first make sure it's really your SQL that is slow. What does `explain (analyze, buffers) SELECT * FROM ppm.f_pp_all_s(?)`  show you? (replacing the `?` with an actual value). Not performance related, but you don't need to use a `CallableStatement` to run a SELECT query. A `PreparedStatement` will do just fine

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name What do you mean, I should check first if it's the SQL?

Comment: Maybe the SQL statement isn't slow, but your Java code. So your first step to analyze this, should be to run your SELECT statement from a SQL client (outside of your program) and look at the execution plan. If it's a PL/pgSQL function you should extract the actual queries from it, and measure their runtime individually.

Comment: And if it turns out, your function is too slow, we need to see the code of your stored function, not the Java code.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ok, I don't just have access to the function of the PostGreSQL database. Assuming it was the Java code, what should / should be changed. Or you could change the Java code anyway, even if it's not because of this, right?

Comment: If your program can connect to the Post**g**eSQL database and your program runs locally on your computer, then you can connect to the database as well outside of your Java program.

Comment: No, unfortunately that is not possible. The database runs on a separate server, like the backend. The backend is in a cloud which communicates with the DB via a firewall. I have no access to the DB locally because I have a dynamic IP and I would need a fixed IP.

Comment: First measure how long does DBVerbindung function take with adding some log lines. If it takes too long, then try to use a DB pool with idle connections...

Comment: When I connect it takes 0.3 milliseconds. Likewise when I add a record. A large picture with 3MB and approx. 30 fields takes 3 seconds to save

Comment: How long does the sql query take in the code you show?  How many rows is it returning?